# Would it be possible to lose a network connection in 2009 and re anable network connection years later in 2021

Tags: wallet-recovery

I still live in the same address as I did 15 years ago 2009 I pressed the generate button on bitcoin Qt as instructed via invitation email and was actively mining bitcoin I never logged in back then as it was not needed, when plugging a different computer later but in same premises in 2021 it asked to clone to network and installed a wallet.dat file is it possible the wallet.dat file that was created in 2021 could be the same wallet.dat from 2009 if it the network re-enabled after 15 years?

Answer (score 1):

No, wallets are generated on basis of random number generation which is completely unrelated to your IP address. If you don’t have a copy of your original *wallet.dat*, you will be unable to access the coins you mined back then.

Comment: i have a wallet.dat Murch but it was created when i reconnected to network in same house 15 years later i only pressed the button to begin mining and then left until 15 years later connected an old computer and when asked installing bitcoin-qt it ask me to connect to cloned network to what i agreed, it started up as it does but left a lot of files including PGP, GPNU, BASE58.ORACLE,FILESWALLET.DATand many many more files.

Comment: also if i have all the required files and folders and have ultimate trust keys in my name alongside Gavin Anderson i am sure theirs is a way i will be able to gain access to my mined bitcoins from 2009 if all these files and key all check out

Comment: I’m confused, do you have your original wallet.dat from the same computer as 15 years ago, or a new wallet.dat? If you have the original wallet.dat, that’s all you need. You should make a few backups of it, and then try to import it into a modern Bitcoin Core.

Comment: this is what i am saying my network was chipped but still mined these bitcoins but never registered on the network until i re conected on a computer of relatively same as back then plugged in to network and some how when connecting bitcoin qt it asked to connect to old network and started up bitcoin qt,was a bit mad after that but seen things moving around on the blockchain that was quite crazy transactions x 50 in multiple transactions happening in block 068,i have a few back ups,things going on for three weeks speak soon thank for hearing me out.

Comment: I’m having a hard time understanding what you are trying to tell me. It sounds like you have the old computer with the software from 2009. Since there were some changes in the peer-to-peer protocol since then, I’m not sure you would be able to connect to the Bitcoin network. However, any new version of Bitcoin Core should be able to synchronize your old wallet. Whatever coins you held and haven’t spent should still be available. If you have a more concrete question, please edit your post to clarify what you are asking.